# Построение гистограммы в python из экселя

Tags: python, графики

Построена таблица в экселе.
Нужно сделать гистограмму (столбцы) с последним и первым столбцом.
Получилось сделать только линейный график. Знаю, что есть plt.bar(), однако при его применении выходит ошибка.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\sr5.1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 1'])
x = df[2:9]

x.plot(x='Unnamed: 1', y='Unnamed: 4')
plt.grid('True')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, я не правильно использую plt.bar(), но:

```
x = df[2:9]
plt.bar(x='Unnamed: 1', y='Unnamed: 4', alpha=0.5, height=0.8, width=0.4)
plt.grid('True')
plt.show()
```

Ошибка:

> raise munits.ConversionError('Failed to convert value(s) to axis '
> matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'Unnamed: 4'

Comment: рекомендую указать ошибку, которая выдается, как и дать кусок кода, который её вызывает

Answer (score 0):

```py
plt.bar(x='Unnamed: 1', y='Unnamed: 4', alpha=0.5, height=0.8, width=0.4)
```

Ну как бы тут вообще датафрейм у вас никак не участвует, `matplotlib` просто не понимает, где брать данные и пытается их брать из предоставленных вами строк, ну и не может он их нормально отрисовать. Ну то есть надо было делать так:

```py
plt.bar(x=x['Unnamed: 1'], y=x['Unnamed: 4'], alpha=0.5, height=0.8, width=0.4)
```

Но на самом деле так тоже не получится из-за того, что по оси `x` у вас строки (или по какой-то другой причине, мне лень разбираться), в общем, лучше просто укажите тип графика в той команде, которой вы выше рисовали, так можно:

```py
x.plot(x='Unnamed: 1', y='Unnamed: 4', kind='bar')
```

Но вообще, если хотите красивых графиков, лучше изучите `seaborn`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='Unnamed: 1', y='Unnamed: 4', data=x, alpha=0.5)
```